# Python (Numpy) Can't rename columns - they become "NaN"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

found the below on the pandas doucmentation but it's just making the existing columns become NaN which I don't understand. Any help really appreciated

df is the dataframe below

| Div | FTHG | FTAG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EO | 2 | 3 |
| EO | 5 | 4 |

```
df.rename(columns={'Div': 'Division',
 'FTHG': 'Full_Time_Home_Goals',
 'FTAG': 'Full_Time_Away_Goals'})
```

Comment: have you checked with `inplace=True` ? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html

Comment: What is `df`? please edit it in to the question

Comment: thank you for the quick reply, still get the same issue.

Comment: @David27 Please edit in what is `df`.

Comment: What is the output of `df.columns`?

Comment: have updated this to show the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Your rename is correct, but it doesn't do anything persistent. In order to actually change the values of df you have two options:

## Use inplace=True

```py
# Making a copy or it will be confusing to run different examples
df_inplace = df.copy()
df_inplace.rename(columns={'Div': 'Division',
 'FTHG': 'Full_Time_Home_Goals',
 'FTAG': 'Full_Time_Away_Goals'},
 inplace= True)
```

## Assign the output to a df

```py
# making a new df to make examples more clear, but
#  changing df_new= to df= will also work
df_new = df.rename(columns={'Div': 'Division',
 'FTHG': 'Full_Time_Home_Goals',
 'FTAG': 'Full_Time_Away_Goals'})
```

Comment: this didnt work unfortunately                                                                                                               AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-346-51b8db9e7d4e> in <module>
      1 df_inplace = df.copy()
----> 2 df_inplace.rename.rename(columns={'Div': 'Division',
      3  'FTHG': 'Full_Time_Home_Goals',
      4  'FTAG': 'Full_Time_Away_Goals',

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'rename'

Comment: this has worked using rename actually, thank you so much!

Comment: glad it worked - I just noticed I had an error in my code (which happens when I don't run it lol), i wrote df.rename.rename instead of just .rename. I edited it to make it correct